# Merging 2 website pages likes?

Tags: php, facebook

I have a website that I added the Facebook like button to it. Assume the website url is "www.xyz.com"

In this website I have articles, each of which has an id in the url like this "www.xyz.com/3/some-text-here"

In my website "www.xyz.com" and "www.xyz.com/3/title-here" refer to the same contents. My question is how to tell Facebook that these links are the same so if a user liked or shared one of these web pages then both of the pages will get the same numbers of likes and shares.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably meta canonical can do it.

Comment: Take a look at the FB docs. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button You should be able to set the `data-href` attrib of the like button to do what you want, or as @machineaddict suggested, meta canonical.

Comment: Also, `og:url`. (Look under the "I need to move a page to a different URL" header.)

Comment: yup that works for me, the data-href i mean. Thank you guys

Comment: @Riad NP, glad everything worked out! :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set the data-href property, in one of the pages, to the other page.
reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button